# Replace tabs in a string with several spaces

Tags: c++, regex, string

Can anyone suggest a good way to replace tabs in a `std::string` with multiple spaces such as "    " (4 spaces)?

I've attempted to use this code but this failed to replace them:

`std::regex_replace(cinput, std::regex("[ \t]"), "    ");`

Comment: You want a replaced copy, or do you want to replace in-place?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Either one is fine, as long as it outputs a string with no tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `std::regex` to do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string const text = "Quick\tbrown\tfox";
  std::string output;
  std::regex const tab(R"(\t)");

  std::regex_replace(back_inserter(output), begin(text), end(text), tab,
                     "    " /* 4 spaces */);

  std::cout << '\n' << output << '\n';
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRABmAJykr6ADJ5aTAA5ZwAjTGIuXgAHVCFCc1o7Rxd3L1j4szp/QJCncMieI0wTLNoGAmZiAmTnV09i0sSKqoIc4LCIqKNK6trUhqFetoCO/K6eAEojVAdiZA4pHTcA5EcsAGpNNxtzIeJMZidt7E0ZAEFl1fXMLZ3CCOYiYhOzy%2B0V2jWHTe2bA%2BAmHErwuVy%2BNzuNn2AWAIMuFwCBA2TmYAQgky2AHZ9BcNhshugQCBoeoNmhaEMNgQgUjtgARLbabQARQceGQAGtNABWGwEULEVAAd1oPL5NGBTO2OPOeIJRJJwA2swI0QcBGlbzlBEJIABQLJdEplVCEAASjptBAxQRJpa7W4ZVr8TqifrxAB9A7RVQLCChZicj0BETVCIQFVq22kDbhYBo6niaMbHwQRPJk2kZ14nO5vN5y25wsAegAVBtuPjooHMEINqXiw6nbiXbq0OrIX8NmAlrzaD3Oztleqo4ObN3ezZ%2B0tHW9NJi6VJpqxpNz5K5ZPJUNIbAYDPjZvNbstOPICNI5JNphyQNwZAA6bjcHjcgAc3I8bgAbF/X1%2BVNI3DrheW7SPIQggDIpDnpu0xwLAMCICgqBONEeDsGQFAQGgqHoV0axqMAnAyDInB8Oh1LEBB/ogaQoQBFUACe0inqQOFOFYBAAPK0KwzGbqQWAouo7C0fgBymHgAButa0UCmDIOqixyOQ9AlLRrB4AKTF2FgtEEMQeBOCxS58HQjAsKJRT8AQwhiJIAlKGRqjqCge56CoWkQZA0yoNEZQQVIAC0BL0loegGJwmIbEFADqbCsDFsU0sQzAxVxbjgSUCllJY1j9K4ZE%2BO0eQFMoGQJHQBXlXElW0CVnSFI0OXNMM1VkcYLV0C01QNeMTVDK07U9K0fVlZw0xCIeCxcMuq7AQJ25SOIf5BV%2BlYEaSxH3g%2BnAbBAuCECQjJuGRGx2LhGEnRN53uboZ4gVepA3twHj3piHjcG42hfm43IyO%2BX7ckDAFSEBpDGc%2Bj4eDwnBMl%2B2jvm4mLraQG4qUt4GQdBj2kPBSGRuq5CUDhaEYcomD4M8yg2UwbAcNZ5l2RItFCql0QmXNUhrmjtFLSeGxCoQCAbCtX5rRtLlKttu0PbB0wIIcWCROioPg8Zb73v976vpimLIzwCPfrzi1gUY2MwZe14gD9948DIn3aF9v5wyjoOZSbGNm5bpn437SCk3hmEkyhZNdERnBkVQFERNRoS0fRtBMSZbEoRx9A8XxYmYMJwCiQJ4ktTJgUqfJinUrRiLqQJmnacQjG6cpZ6GcZUintMtOWQzvA2czDkqUo2gqIRbkRR5tfearfkBdIIU6mFd1RUlCVJSlaVBRlWVNBYEA%2BMNxWjKVEykBVZTDafiRjcfnWSd1bX2HUyg32UPUjLkjVP/fKSFSNvWHx/E0ZhzBmoAlc3MFpe2WqtdaGxgDIGQBsSOdt9qHWeNdGMF0w7EBOtoDEu4x73RxvLZ67g3D3jcBQyhVCqFq3kJDTg0MoraH1q%2BDwrDMQfG5J7UCUgsZQR9nBRCEAkCEwIMTbCocg4228FTEgNNzJ0ysj3JmIgWYCTZswDmbdTJgJ5ujHhyxtCC2FqLaBlY4EIKQaxARCslZdFVmA9WIBNba2YT9YixFmEg30aQTG5t%2BGPWthQx8UUPysK/B4bknA/xcLAR7HxfibGg20BAnhcsrakBklRRIt4gA%3D)

Do note that `std::regex` implementations are notoriously slow both to compile and to run. You may be interested in other regex libraries like [Boost.Regex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) and [CTRE](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`replace()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string x = "abc\tdef\ttest";
    cout << x << "\n";

    string fi = "\t"; //tab
    string se = "    "; //four spaces

    auto it = x.find(fi);
    while (it != string::npos)
    {
        x.replace(it, fi.size(), se);
        it = x.find(fi);
    }
    cout << x;
}
```

Output:

```
abc     def     test
abc    def    test
```

Or with [`regex_replace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) as in your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string x = "abc\tdef\ttest";
    cout << x << "\n";

    string fi = "\t"; //tab
    string se = "%%"; //some test characters, you can switch back to four spaces

    x = regex_replace(x, std::regex(fi), se);
    cout << x;
}
```

Output:

```
abc     def     test
abc%%def%%test
```